# Redux in NextJS 13 (approuter) - pattern minimizing 'use client'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit, next.js13

Am new to NextJS. Seeing numerous tutorials, including this one from vercel themselves - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux

They have the standard pattern -

1. Create a Redux `Provider`

```
    "use client";
    import {Provider} from "react-redux"
    import {store} from "./store";
    import React from "react";
    
    export default function ReduxProvider({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
        return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
    
    };
```

2. Then use it in a component needing redux. However you need to declare **`'use client'`** for that component

```
    'use client'
    import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import {increment, decrement} from "./counterSlice";
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
    
    const Counter = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      return (
        <div>
          <Button onClick={() => { dispatch(increment()); }}> + </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => { dispatch(decrement()); }}> - </Button>
        </div>
        );
    };
    export default Counter;
```

This is a very simple/simplified example, in reality, these components could be more involved.

Question is - does this defeats the purpose of SSR in NextJS just because we are using Redux, as all components that are marked by `use client` will not be SSR generated.

Instead, would it be a correct pattern to reduce the CSR components into a `redux` based component with `use client` in it, so that redux calls can be made and then have a non-client (SSR) component that is called which is SSR generated. Sample below -

Have the client component with Redux calls

```
    'use client'
    import {increment, decrement} from "./counterSlice";
    import {CounterSSR} from './CounterSSR'
    
    const CounterClient = () => {
      return (
        <CounterSSR
            onIncrement={() => { dispatch(increment()); }}
            onDecrement={() => { dispatch(decrement()); }} />
        );
    };
    export default CounterClient;
```

and then have the SSR component `CounterSSR` as below

```
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
    
    const CounterSSR = (props) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Button onClick={props.onIncrement}> + </Button>
          <Button onClick={props.onDecrement}> - </Button>
        </div>
        );
    };
    export default CounterSSR;
```

Problem is, with this, I end up having 2 copies of a component, one with logic (redux calls) and other a 'dumb' UI component for rendering.

What would be the recommendation for this?

Comment: Redux was built with client side React in mind, so you're not going to benefit from SSR features if you're building an application architecture based on Redux. This is a really good question and if there's a solid answer out there then awesome, but from my experience (given the current state of Redux and NextJS) I think it's going to be a bit of a waste trying to make any of your redux linked components SSR friendly.

Comment: That said, even client components will be SSRed on first page load. Don't confuse SSR and RSC. RSC runs only on the server, but every client component will also be SSRed on first page load before running in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hooks, you can dispatch actions directly using the store reference(the good old way)

```
'use client'
import store from "<path to redux store>";
import {increment, decrement} from "./counterSlice";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const Counter = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => { store.dispatch(increment()); }}> + </Button>
      <Button onClick={() => { store.dispatch(decrement()); }}> - </Button>
    </div>
    );
};
export default Counter;
```

Even if you use the above code, you still have to declare `use client` since you are using event handlers(onClick) to perform actions, which is only allowed in client components.

If you are reading data from store, you can directly use the store to access the state instead of using the `useSelector` hook.